# How should I include names which are written in non-Latin scripts in a list of software authors?

Tags: names

I have a list of the authors of a software program, some of whose contributors are from such places as China and Russia. I would like to include both their transliterated Latin-script names and their actual names (written in their native scripts) in the list of authors.

What is the best way to handle the formatting of the names in such cases?

For instance, is:

> Transliterated Name -- ChineseName `<em@a.il>`

or

> Transliterated Name (ChineseName) `<em@a.il>`

or some other style of presentation preferable?

Also, is there a recognized standard that covers the way in which names displayed as both their transliterated Latin-script versions and their native-script versions should be written?

Comment: It certainly seems like a good idea to include the names as they are written in their native scripts in order to provide a baseline reference. This is because how names are transliterated varies considerably from one language to another; it is presumably quite possible that the program will be used by speakers of a variety of different languages, some of which could have very different transliteration conventions from those that are applied in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the second option is the best because the dash sign looks similar to the Chinese sign for "one".
See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%80

In that case, it might create confusion.

Comment: It is what I have used in the end.